# Click object to expand, moving next-floating objects outside viewport (instead of below)

Tags: jquery, css, viewport, expand

Let's say I've got 3 squares within one container, next to each other, each 33.33% of the viewport. When I click one of them, that one will expand to full viewport width and show the hidden content, while the others stay next to that one, but now appear outside of the viewport. The container should be horizontally scrollable, so you can still access the other ones.

I'm currently at the point that I can expand one of the squares, but the other two will automatically moved below it, instead of next to it.

How would I achieve this?

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/7pg0buL8/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    width:450px;
    height:150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.tile {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: width .5s;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
}

.tile.expanded {
    width:100%;
}
```

```js
$(function () {
    $('.tile').click(function () {
        $('.tile.expanded').removeClass('expanded');
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one with the simple rule nowrap

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:450px;
    height:150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;

}

.tile {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: width .5s;
    background-color:green;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tile.expanded {
    width:100%;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7pg0buL8/5/)**

Comment: And display-inline, instead of floats I noticed. However, that is indeed working! Too bad inline-blocks give a strange whitespace between em.

Comment: yes...if you put the div´s in the same line...the gap goes off. I update the demo

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
.container {
   width:550px;
    height:150px;

    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.tile {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: width .5s;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
}

.tile.expanded {
    width:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solutions with fixed `width` for containers: http://jsfiddle.net/7pg0buL8/4/

Comment: How would I get access to the tiles without a width then..? Without a width (or zero width) they are unclickable. See it as a horizontal accordion.

Comment: I've updated fiddle - check if You think about sth like here: http://jsfiddle.net/7pg0buL8/4/